# UML Statechart Delving Into vs Internal Transition

Tags: uml, transition, internals, statechart

I have a question about statechart diagrams below;

[image]

I suppose that, in UML, it is possible. In this case, execution order is S1 enter, S3 enter. Am I right?
And In the next diagram, what is execution order when occured transiton from "any other state" to s1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the first diagram :**

> execution order is S1 enter, S3 enter. Am I right?

yes you are right, from the standard  [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) § 14.2.3.4.5
*Entering a State* page 310 :

> Explicit entry: If the incoming Transition or its continuations terminate on a directly contained substate of the
> composite State, then that substate becomes active and its entry Behavior is executed after the execution of the
> entry Behavior of the containing composite State.

**For the second diagram :**

- it seems to use an *entryPoint pseudostate* (badly drawn), but the transition from *any other state* is not going to it but to S1, so to the *initial pseudostate*, the execution is *entryActS1* then *entryActS2*.
- if it is not an entry point but a local transition from the border that changes nothing from *any other state* and the execution is also *entryActS1* then *entryActS2*.

---

**About the transition indicated *internal***

the transition from the possible *entryPoint pseudostate* or from the border is indicated *internal*, but internal transitions are self transitions where the source and target are the same state, as said in the standard [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) §14.2.3.8.1
*Transition kinds relative to source* page 314 :

> kind = internal is a special case of a local Transition that is a self-transition (i.e., with the same source and
> target States), such that the State is never exited (and, thus, not re-entered), which means that no exit or entry
> Behaviors are executed when this Transition is executed. This kind of Transition can only be defined if the
> source Vertex is a State.

So the second diagram is illegal :

- in case of an *entry pseudostate* rather than to be *internal* the transition from it is *local* as said in the standard [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) § 14.5.11.8 *Constraints* page 361 :

> state_is_local
>
> A Transition with kind local must have a composite State or an entry point as its source.

- in case of a transition from the border it can be *local* or *external*, but as it is drawn it is *local*, see standard [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) page 335 figure 14.34 *Local Transitions* and Figure 14.35 *External Transitions* to see the difference of drawing

Comment: Thanks. In link below, is diagram 1 not legal? It seems that, it similar to my diagram-2...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666095/uml-state-machines-local-vs-external-transition

Comment: @kaernk In the link you give the transition from the border is not indicates *internal* like it is in the second diagram in your question, the transition from the border is *local*

Comment: @kaernk do you understand the difference ? I put the references to the standard in my answer to allow you to go in it in case

Comment: I suppose that I understand it. You say that internal transition (such as my drawn) different from local transition. Am I right?

Comment: @kaernk yes transitions have 3 possible kind : external, local and internal (see 14.2.4.9
TransitionKind page 334 of the standard)

Comment: I agree that my drawn is bad. Actually, I wanted to ask local transition. In my drawn, if it local transition instead of external that is illegal, what is execution order?

Comment: @kaernk for local from the border I already answer in the last version of my answer, so the same from the external state